# Instagram API error 500 UTF-8 hashtags with enforced signature

Tags: jakarta-ee, utf-8, instagram, urlencode, instagram-api

I am receiving 500 error from a simple instagram GET request.  My code works when the hashtag contains normal ascii characters, or when my app has the checkbox "Enforce signed requests" unchecked.  But I cannot get anything to work when I try with a utf8 hashtag and signed requests enforced.  I saw that signed requests will be mandatory soon, so I need it to work.  I want to get all images for a tag like #über.

```
public static String signRequest(String key, String data) throws Exception {
    Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
    SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(key.getBytes("UTF-8"), "HmacSHA256");
    sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
    return Hex.encodeHexString(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(data.getBytes("UTF-8")));
}

public static void getLatestImagesForHashtag(String hashtag, String client_id, String secret) throws Exception {
    String endpoint = "/tags/" + URLEncoder.encode(hashtag, "UTF-8") + "/media/recent";
    String request_data = endpoint + "|client_id=" + client_id;
    System.out.println("SIGNING DATA: " + request_data);
    String signature = InstagramUtil.signRequest(secret, request_data);
    System.out.println("SIG VAL: " + signature);
    String url = "https://api.instagram.com/v1" + endpoint + "?client_id=" + client_id + "&sig=" + signature;
    URL obj;
    try {
        obj = new URL(url);
        HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
        //Blah blah blah
```

And the response I get

```
Info:   SIGNING DATA: /tags/%C3%BCber/media/recent|client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx
Info:   SIG VAL: 503fd3fb7072eea8284576940b3fe75125a5bbbd9f505f22507776cbb6760d5d
Info:   Sending 'GET' request to URL : https://api.instagram.com/v1/tags/%C3%BCber/media/recent?client_id=xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx&sig=503fd3fb7072eea8284576940b3fe75125a5bbbd9f505f22507776cbb6760d5d
Info:   Response Code : 500
Info:   Response Msg : INTERNAL SERVER ERROR
```

The data response is: Oops, an error occurred.

I have tried many different combinations of encoding the hashtag in the endpoint and in the signature data.  It is odd that I receive a 500 error and not a 403 if it is a signature problem.  Am I doing something wrong with encoding?

Comment: I have exactly the same problem and I just opened a bug on the instagram's bug tool. Hope they answer quickly.

Comment: I also submitted a bug report to instagram about a month ago but unfortunately they dont reply.  They actually say that they "might" contact you if they need more information.  So I can only assume they don't need any more information and are working on a fix.

Comment: Are you sure that the Strings in `signRequest` are human readable text? There you could try "ISO-8859-1". If the strings were abused to contain binary bytes. An erroneous `String` usage i.o. `byte[]` makes problems and is less performant.

Comment: It was a bug. The sign request is made up of a secret key (static string), the endpoint and client id. The problem was the utf8 characters in the endpoint were not handled properly even when url escaped correctly. The bug has been fixed now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this issue is apparently a bug of Instagram API.
I tested various request patterns.

**"Enforce signed requests" is enabled**

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=%e3%81%82&sig=<correct sig>
```

-> **500 (expected 200)**

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=%e3%81%82&sig=<incorrect sig>
```

-> **500 (expected 403)**

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=%e3%81%82
```

-> 403 (as expected)

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=abc&sig=<correct sig>
```

-> 200 (as expected)

**"Enforce signed requests" is disabled**

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=%e3%81%82&sig=<correct sig>
```

-> 200 (as expected)

```
/v1/tags/search?access_token=<access token>&q=%e3%81%82&sig=<incorrect sig>
```

-> 403 (as expected)

When "Enforce signed requests" is enabled, a request which has non-ascii utf-8 characters in its uri always get 500. If turn off it, everything work fine. This is apparently not an issue caused by incorrect sig parameter or wrong encoding.
I already reported this issue to Instagram via bugtool 10 days ago. No reaction from them so far.
(Sorry to answer again. My 1st answer was deleted.)

**[UPDATE 5 Sep.]**
**At last, this issue seems to be fixed.**
My IG app works fine with *Enforce Signed Requests* setting now.
Note: If an endpoint uri has url-encoded characters (such as /tags/%E3%81%82/media/recent), you need to generate sig parameter from decoded endpoint string.

Comment: Yes, it works now, great.  And I also received an email from them too :)

Answer (score 1):

I just received a message from Instagram telling me that it really was a bug and it is now fixed! \o/

> Hi, Thanks for your report and interest in the Instagram platform. The
>   issue has been fixed. Best, Jackie
>   - Instagram team