# Signing request with non-latin params values

Tags: instagram, instagram-api

How to properly sign `("Enforce signed requests" Client option)` request with non-latin params values (for example for search endpoint)?

Neither `key=UTF8(value)`, nor `key=URLEncode(UTF8(value))` working correctly, API response with

> "Oops, an error occurred."

body instead of the documented response of

```
{ "code": 403, 
     "error_type": "OAuthForbiddenException", 
     "error_message": "..."
}.
```

Comment: Non-latin characters in "endpoint" also produces same error.

Comment: I have the same problem and I opened a bug on Instagram's but tool yesterday. It sound to me that is an api error (because this response has 500 code - Internal Server Error) - I suggest you to follow this thread either: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32170756/instagram-api-error-500-utf-8-hashtags-with-enforced-signature